# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{2^{2^n}} = 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Prove that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n!}{2^{2^n}} = 0$$ 
I don't think I can use L'Hopital rule. I can't think of other ways. Do I need non-elementary results to prove this? I know Stirling's formula but I can't see how it helps. Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{n!}{2^{2^n}}$. Then by using absurdly weak estimates
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{2^n}}<\frac{2^n}{2^{2^n}}< \frac{2^{2^n-1}}{2^{2^n}}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: We have: $\dfrac{n}{2^{\frac{2^n}{n}}}< \dfrac{n}{2^n}< \dfrac{1}{n}$

Comment: Reread the question, please.

Comment: @GitGud $(n!)^{1/n}<(n^n)^{1/n}=n$

Comment: @Agawa001 It was me who misread the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $n!$ is the product of $n$ numbers smaller than or equal to $n$, we have $n! \leq n^n < (2^n)^n=2^{n^2}$.

Now $$\frac{n!}{2^{2^n}} < \frac{2^{n^2}}{2^{2^n}}$$